# How to find time in sh scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find a way to get date and time separately. For date I can do:

```
date -u +%d/%m/%Y
```

What should I do to find the time in the following format?

```
hh/mm/ss
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date command can give you the time part as well. Check out the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) (or type `man date` on your command line) for more details.

```
date -u +%H:%M:%S
```

Or to meet your formatting requirement of HH/MM/SS:

```
date -u +%H/%M/%S
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date -u +%H/%M/%S
```

Comment: btw is this for current time?

Comment: @GuzzyD - just as current as your date ;) the '-u' argument on both gives "Coordinated Universal Time"

Comment: so wat if i want it to view the current time in also the time zone +8:00 ?

Comment: @GuzzyD: Try `date -u -d "now UTC-8"` or `TZ=UTC-8 date` (I'm not sure why the signs are reversed).